# Boto3: when calling the TagResource operation: Long arn format must be used for tagging operations

Tags: boto3, amazon-ecs

I have created my ECS, services and tasks using Cloudformation Template, where enableECSManagedTags or propagate tags are not used.

As soon as my stacks are created, I was trying to run below to add the tags

```
service_tag_response = self.ecs_client.tag_resource(resourceArn=self.service_arn_name,
                                                                tags=self.service_tag)
```

Then i got the error, `when calling the TagResource operation: Long arn format must be used for tagging operations`

Then I tried to enable longresource option, and my script looks like below

```
response = self.ecs_client.put_account_setting(name='serviceLongArnFormat', value='enabled')
        if 'ResponseMetadata' in response and \
                response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
            service_tag_response = self.ecs_client.tag_resource(resourceArn=self.service_arn_name,
                                                                tags=self.service_tag)
```

Then also I'm getting the same error.
Does anyone know, how to fix this error?
And my service arn is : `arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:12345678901:service/my-service`

Comment: What is `service_arn_name`? Seems to be its only name, not the full arn.

Comment: my service arn is `arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:12345678901:service/my-service`, so you are suggesting only the `my-service` would suffice. let me try. it's also confusing that in boto3 manual they suggest the arm of the service and in aws realm arn starts with `arn`

Comment: The error message says: "**Long arn format must** be used for tagging operations". This suggests you have to use full arn, not service name.

Comment: as per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/userguide/ecs-account-settings.html, I also used, `arn:aws:ecs:eu-west-1:12345678901:service/mycluster/my-service` then it complains `when calling the TagResource operation: The specified service does not have the longArn format. Only services created after opting in will have the new format`. i'm using the arn name in my script,  So what do you mean by use `Long arn format`?

Comment: Example of arn in tag-resource is [here](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ecs/tag-resource.html). Maybe this will give you some idea on what's wrong.

Answer (score -1):

It appears that you have not enabled 'serviceLongArnFormat' Account Setting for the user/role that created the ECS service.

To have the ability to add tags to an ECS service, it requires that you opt-in to the new Amazon Resource Name (ARN) and resource identifier (ID) formats per [1](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-using-tags.html). In order to opt-in for new ARN format, please see [2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-modifying-longer-id-settings.html)

You can also refer to this blog post [3](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/migrating-your-amazon-ecs-deployment-to-the-new-arn-and-resource-id-format-2/) for more information about this. Note that, existing resources do not receive the new ARN format until they are re-created.

Comment: I hear you and understand perfectly. But my point is when I created the ECS resources I didn't opt in for long format arn. That's why when I ask for the resources arn details I get the old format way. Then while tagging the old format why it will force ask me to choose the long arn. from the error what it appears, AWS is forcing to choose the longarn format. So my question is it mandatory to opt in before creating the resouces? because I don't have this error, if I enable longarn format before my ECS resource creation.

Comment: "To use this feature, it requires that you opt-in to the new Amazon Resource Name (ARN) and resource identifier (ID) formats. " - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs-using-tags.html

Comment: This is not helpful as the error persists after enabling serviceLongArnFormat for the account, based on the question.